# "Left Ctrl to first layout; Right Ctrl to last layout" breaks Copy/Paste shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma-5

Enabling this option in "Keyboard settings" -> "Additional settings" -> "Layout switch" breaks all Ctrl-related shortcuts in system (such as Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, etc).

[image]

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is.In the gnome tweak

```
Keyboard & Mouse > Additonal Layout Option > Switching to another layout
```

Comment: 1) Question is about KDE, not Gnome; 2) How's your answer related to the topic of my question, e.g. messing up Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V shortcuts?

Comment: Emmmmm...your title and picture is confused

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my native. Subject is that enabling this option makes all other CTRL-key shortcuts in system don't work.

Comment: Haha, me, too. Your description is clear actually. It's my bad comprehension and the impluse of being a new contributor.